# Validate XML against XSD schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xmlschema

I have an XML file to validate against XSD schema. This is how my XML file looks like.

```xml
<service>
  <id>myid</id>
  <name>myname</name>
  <arg>arg1</arg>
  <arg>arg2</arg>
</service>
```

These are the validation rules.

- `id` and `name` are unique and required. There cannot be more than one element from those.
- `arg` can be repeat
- The order does not matter. Elements can be in any order.

This is the XSD file I created for this.

```xml
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="service">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">

        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="id" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="arg" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>

        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

When I try to validate with this (https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html) online validator this works. But it now shows any error even when there are two `id` elements or no `id` element.

```xml
<service>
  <id>myid</id>
  <id>anotherid</id>
  <name>myname</name>
  <arg>arg1</arg>
  <arg>arg2</arg>
</service>
```

This should be wrong since there are two `id` elements. How to have both repeatable and not repeatable elements in `choice`  elements. `Sequence` is not possible here since the order does not matter.

```xml
<service>
  <name>myname</name>
  <arg>arg1</arg>
  <arg>arg2</arg>
</service>
```

This should fail since the `id` element is not there.

Comment: Have you tried using xs:group?

Comment: @BrynLewis even inside `group` doesn't I have to use `choice`?

Comment: I don't think this is achievable without changing the xml data structure. If you use the ```xs:sequence``` option all elements must be in order.

If you use the ```xs:choice``` option with the ```maxoccurs``` restriction it will create as much elements that the maxxoccurs is set on.

the ```xs:all``` option also gives you the freedom to have elements in a random order. but the ```maxoccurs``` restriction is not possible here. 

The solution could be a type that holds the unbounded arg element and assign an element to that resulting into a <args><arg></arg><arg></arg></args> structure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a choice. If you allow the elements to be in any order (using UnorderedSet) then you are not allowed to set maxOccurs > 1. If you use a repeating choice, you cannot validate the number of occurrences because you match one *occurrence* of the tag for each occurrence of the choice. But if you use a sequence, you have to accept that the tags must be in the correct order.
Almost everybody just accepts the need for ordered tags in XML - even though it is inconvenient.